# python plydata is different ply file

Tags: python, ply-file-format

my ply file is

ply
format ascii 1.0
element vertex 49152
property float x
property float y
property float z
property uchar red
property uchar green
property uchar blue
property float cx
property float cy
property float depth
property uchar alpha
element face 0
property list uchar int vertex_indices
end_header
-1.6746984 0.013880749 -2.5484023 0 0 0 0.0 0.0 2.4375  255
-1.685372 0.012589366 -2.5640535 0 0 0 0.0 1.0 2.453125  255
-1.6947021 0.011268582 -2.5776653 0 0 0 0.0 2.0 2.4667969  255
-1.7067163 0.009953017 -2.5953326 0 0 0 0.0 3.0 2.484375  255
-1.6972555 0.008469224 -2.5805016 0 0 0 0.0 4.0 2.4707031  255
-1.701216 0.0070825107 -2.5859785 0 0 0 0.0 5.0 2.4765625  255
-1.7051762 0.005689003 -2.5914524 0 0 0 0.0 6.0 2.4824219  255
-1.7010844 0.0042535556 -2.5847487 0 0 0 0.0 7.0 2.4765625  255
-1.7050444 0.0028533721 -2.5902197 0 0 0 0.0 8.0 2.4824219  255
-1.7116877 0.0014538177 -2.5997443 0 0 0 0.0 9.0 2.4921875  255
-1.7116214 3.0458676e-05 -2.5991254 0 0 0 0.0 10.0 2.4921875  255
-1.714239 -0.0013900065 -2.602561 0 0 0 0.0 11.0 2.4960938  255
-1.7141727 -0.0028156305 -2.6019413 0 0 0 0.0 12.0 2.4960938  255
-1.7167896 -0.004242891 -2.605374 0 0 0 0.0 13.0 2.5  255
-1.7180649 -0.0056728492 -2.606779 0 0 0 0.0 14.0 2.5019531  255
-1.722023 -0.0071107624 -2.6122336 0 0 0 0.0 15.0 2.5078125  255

When importing and using the plydata library in Python, the result is as follows:

array([(-0.3809132 , -1.2006984, -1.5983648, 0, 0, 0, 0.,  0., 1.5927734, 255),
(-0.38256204, -1.2042053, -1.6008415, 0, 0, 0, 0.,  1., 1.5966797, 255),
(-0.38124126, -1.2004267, -1.5957162, 0, 0, 0, 0.,  2., 1.5917969, 255),
(-0.38652503, -1.2128427, -1.6074688, 0, 0, 0, 0.,  3., 1.6064453, 255),
(-0.38256013, -1.2025843, -1.5955989, 0, 0, 0, 0.,  4., 1.59375  , 255),
(-0.3838817 , -1.2052839, -1.5972235, 0, 0, 0, 0.,  5., 1.5966797, 255),
(-0.38255692, -1.201502 , -1.5921094, 0, 0, 0, 0.,  6., 1.5917969, 255),
(-0.38123024, -1.1977184, -1.5870006, 0, 0, 0, 0.,  7., 1.5869141, 255),
(-0.38056415, -1.1955545, -1.5835791, 0, 0, 0, 0.,  8., 1.5839844, 255),
(-0.3802284 , -1.1942004, -1.5810013, 0, 0, 0, 0.,  9., 1.5820312, 255),
(-0.37956005, -1.1920346, -1.5775859, 0, 0, 0, 0., 10., 1.5791016, 255),
(-0.37889057, -1.1898679, -1.5741737, 0, 0, 0, 0., 11., 1.5761719, 255),
(-0.37855196, -1.1885115, -1.5716035, 0, 0, 0, 0., 12., 1.5742188, 255),
(-0.37821257, -1.1871544, -1.5690355, 0, 0, 0, 0., 13., 1.5722656, 255),
(-0.37753987, -1.184985 , -1.5656323, 0, 0, 0, 0., 14., 1.5693359, 255),
(-0.37686592, -1.1828147, -1.5622325, 0, 0, 0, 0., 15., 1.5664062, 255),

Can you tell me how the conversion is done with the result?

ply
format ascii 1.0
element vertex 49152
property float x
property float y
property float z
property uchar red
property uchar green
property uchar blue
property float cx
property float cy
property float depth
property uchar alpha
element face 0
property list uchar int vertex_indices
end_header
-1.6746984 0.013880749 -2.5484023 0 0 0 0.0 0.0 2.4375  255
-1.685372 0.012589366 -2.5640535 0 0 0 0.0 1.0 2.453125  255
-1.6947021 0.011268582 -2.5776653 0 0 0 0.0 2.0 2.4667969  255
-1.7067163 0.009953017 -2.5953326 0 0 0 0.0 3.0 2.484375  255
-1.6972555 0.008469224 -2.5805016 0 0 0 0.0 4.0 2.4707031  255
-1.701216 0.0070825107 -2.5859785 0 0 0 0.0 5.0 2.4765625  255
-1.7051762 0.005689003 -2.5914524 0 0 0 0.0 6.0 2.4824219  255
-1.7010844 0.0042535556 -2.5847487 0 0 0 0.0 7.0 2.4765625  255
-1.7050444 0.0028533721 -2.5902197 0 0 0 0.0 8.0 2.4824219  255
-1.7116877 0.0014538177 -2.5997443 0 0 0 0.0 9.0 2.4921875  255
-1.7116214 3.0458676e-05 -2.5991254 0 0 0 0.0 10.0 2.4921875  255
-1.714239 -0.0013900065 -2.602561 0 0 0 0.0 11.0 2.4960938  255
-1.7141727 -0.0028156305 -2.6019413 0 0 0 0.0 12.0 2.4960938  255
-1.7167896 -0.004242891 -2.605374 0 0 0 0.0 13.0 2.5  255
-1.7180649 -0.0056728492 -2.606779 0 0 0 0.0 14.0 2.5019531  255
-1.722023 -0.0071107624 -2.6122336 0 0 0 0.0 15.0 2.5078125  255

array([(-0.3809132 , -1.2006984, -1.5983648, 0, 0, 0, 0.,  0., 1.5927734, 255),
(-0.38256204, -1.2042053, -1.6008415, 0, 0, 0, 0.,  1., 1.5966797, 255),
(-0.38124126, -1.2004267, -1.5957162, 0, 0, 0, 0.,  2., 1.5917969, 255),
(-0.38652503, -1.2128427, -1.6074688, 0, 0, 0, 0.,  3., 1.6064453, 255),
(-0.38256013, -1.2025843, -1.5955989, 0, 0, 0, 0.,  4., 1.59375  , 255),
(-0.3838817 , -1.2052839, -1.5972235, 0, 0, 0, 0.,  5., 1.5966797, 255),
(-0.38255692, -1.201502 , -1.5921094, 0, 0, 0, 0.,  6., 1.5917969, 255),
(-0.38123024, -1.1977184, -1.5870006, 0, 0, 0, 0.,  7., 1.5869141, 255),
(-0.38056415, -1.1955545, -1.5835791, 0, 0, 0, 0.,  8., 1.5839844, 255),
(-0.3802284 , -1.1942004, -1.5810013, 0, 0, 0, 0.,  9., 1.5820312, 255),
(-0.37956005, -1.1920346, -1.5775859, 0, 0, 0, 0., 10., 1.5791016, 255),
(-0.37889057, -1.1898679, -1.5741737, 0, 0, 0, 0., 11., 1.5761719, 255),
(-0.37855196, -1.1885115, -1.5716035, 0, 0, 0, 0., 12., 1.5742188, 255),
(-0.37821257, -1.1871544, -1.5690355, 0, 0, 0, 0., 13., 1.5722656, 255),
(-0.37753987, -1.184985 , -1.5656323, 0, 0, 0, 0., 14., 1.5693359, 255),
(-0.37686592, -1.1828147, -1.5622325, 0, 0, 0, 0., 15., 1.5664062, 255),

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).